# Android doesn't apply background color when a shape is defined

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a style for buttons in my app. In order to do that, I created a drawable file with the corner tag. I also created different styles for different button state (normal and disabled). When I apply the style without setting the background attribute, the button have the correct color. But when I set the background attribute with my drawable file, the text color defined in the style.xml works but not the background color. Here is the code : 
values/style.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/button_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonDisableStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/button_color_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonText_color_disabled</item>
</style>
```

drawable/button_shape.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />

<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

main_activity :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/newButton"
    android:text="@string/generate_first"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    />
```

I saw several post about the same problem and I know that it is possible to define the button's background color in the drawable/button_shape.xml but I'd like to keep the style and make it works (I want the shape and the style to be separated). 
Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: The reason this is happening is because you are overriding your style's background by setting one explicitly for your view. I am not sure of a way around this using just xml in your case. You could create a custom Button view and control things from there, but it isn't a direct answer to your question.

Comment: Doing what I want to do here would allow me to change all the app design just by changing the style. As my design is provisional, I didn't wanted to create custom views yet, but I'll probably do it in the final version. But thank you for your answer. Maybe what I ask is not possible. I'll continue searching anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally and after more research, I found a solution. I created 3 xml shape files for the button corresponding to 3 different states. Then I created a 4th xml shape file which includes the 3 others.
Finally, I put a reference to the 4th shape xml file into the button style (in values/style.xml). Here is the code :

drawable/button_disabled.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/buttonText_color_disabled"/>
<padding android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="7dp" />
<corners android:radius= "5dp" />
</shape>
```

drawable/button_pressed.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/button_color_pressed"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius= "5dp" />
</shape>
```

drawable/button_enabled.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/button_color"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius= "5dp" />
 </shape>
```

drawable/button.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />
</selector>
```

values/style.xml :

```
<style name="Custom_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>
```

main_activity :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/newButton"
        android:text="@string/generate_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_info"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        style="@style/Custom_button" />
```